# MAUI Popups, floating windows and containers

Tags: maui

I need to get a popup window that is not bound to the main window but will allow me to determine where on the screen should it appear.

Requirements:

1. I need to be able to decide the size, and location of the new window even if it's on another screen. (I'm already detecting all the screens so this is not an issue)
2. I need to be able to operate / change values on the main window while the new window stays in place and receives commands from the changing values on the first window and displays them (Text for example)
3. The new window should be able to display text but also it would be nice if it would be able to receive a background photo/video.

Is it at all possible in MAUI?
I know how to do that in Windows Forms but it looks like Windows Forms ls out of date and it soon will not be supported.
Also MAUI seems to have a nicer appearance out of the box. I really like it but I'm not sure if what I need to do is doable at the moment?[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Multi-window support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows?view=net-maui-7.0#multi-window-support) in MAUI as Jason suggested.

You can call an Action to invoke the method in main window, or communicate with the **ViewModel** of the main page when you want to receive commands from the changing values on the first window and displays them, see [Data binding and MVVM - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm?view=net-maui-7.0)

Here's the code snippets below for your reference:

```
 private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         Window secondWindow = new Window(new NewPage( FirstImage, "First window String to Second", ( string second) =>
             {
                   CounterBtn.Text = second;
         })) ;
         var displayInfo = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo;
         secondWindow.X = (displayInfo.Width / displayInfo.Density - Window.Width) / 2;
         secondWindow.Y = (displayInfo.Height / displayInfo.Density - Window.Height) / 2;
             Application.Current.OpenWindow(secondWindow);
     }
```

```
 public NewPage(Image firstImage, string firstTitle, Action<string> firstTitleAction)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         SecontTitleLabel.Text = firstTitle;//get the text from first window
    
    
         firstTitleAction("SecondTitle");
     }
```

Comment: Thank you. 
My window now opens but I need an option to open it Maximized and there seems to be no option? 
I mean it opens large but there is still a Windows taskbar visible as well as the windows top bar and I need the new window to cover the entire screen.
What should I do please?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. You can post a new thread for this new issue and I'm glad to help you!